# Найти вызов метода внутри другого метода

Tags: c#, .net

Есть некоторое произвольное выражение, которое внутри себя вызывает некоторый метод F(x). Например `(x)=> {F(x)>F(y)?F(y):F(x/2);}`
Можно ли как-то динамически определить вызывает ли это выражение F(x),а также значения параметров с которыми вызывается F(x) и заменить вызов метода, скажем, константой?
Как я понимаю, нужно действовать через `MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray()`, но что именно там искать ума не приложу

Comment: если выражение это expression tree, то да. в противном случае могут быть сложности

Comment: @Grundy, не могли бы рассказать подробнее про expression tree?

Comment: @Mihail в общем вам никто этого так и не сказал, но задача такая очень нетривиальная. То, что вы получили от метода - это по сути байт-код на IL, чтобы его разобрать, нужно знать этот язык и по сути дебажить этот метод вручную, что не есть просто. Но самое главное, насколько я знаю, заменить исходный метод после изменения кода все равно не удастся. Поэтому, если нужна какая-то более сложная логика в методе, то нужно либо сразу это прописывать, либо переопределять в новом классе наследуемый от текущего.

Comment: @Mihail: [Expression Trees](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees)

Comment: А не пишете ли вы случайно юнит-тесты?

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять за основу код библиотеки для парсинга IL-кода [SDILReader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body).

IL-код представляет собой набор инструкций, состоящих и 1 или 2-байтного кода и операнда из 0-8 байт. Вызов метода осуществляется инструкцией call или callvirt, операндом для нее является metadata token, который идентифицирует метод в контексте определенного модуля. Таким образом, найти все методы, которые вызывает указанный метод, можно так:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
…

public static OpCode FindOpCode(short val)
{
    OpCode ret = OpCodes.Nop;
    FieldInfo[] mas = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
    {
        if (mas[i].FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
        {
            OpCode opcode = (OpCode)mas[i].GetValue(null);
            if (opcode.Value == val)
            {
                ret = opcode;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<MethodBase> GetCalledMethods(MethodInfo mi)
{
    var mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
    var msil = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
    var module = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Module;

    List<MethodBase> methods = new List<MethodBase>();

    short op;
    int n = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (n >= msil.Length) break;

        //получаем код операции
        if (msil[n] == 0xfe)
            op = (short)(msil[n + 1] | 0xfe00);
        else
            op = (short)(msil[n]);

        //найдем имя операции
        OpCode opcode = FindOpCode(op);
        string str = opcode.Name;
        int size = 0;

        //найдем размер операции
        switch (opcode.OperandType)
        {
            case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:  size = 4;  break;
            case OperandType.InlineField: size = 4; break;
            case OperandType.InlineMethod:  size = 4;  break;
            case OperandType.InlineSig: size = 4; break;
            case OperandType.InlineTok: size = 4;  break;
            case OperandType.InlineType: size = 4; break;
            case OperandType.InlineI: size = 4; break;
            case OperandType.InlineI8: size = 8; break;
            case OperandType.InlineNone: size = 0;  break;                        
            case OperandType.InlineR: size = 8;    break;                        
            case OperandType.InlineString: size = 4; break;                        
            case OperandType.InlineSwitch: size = 4; break;                        
            case OperandType.InlineVar: size = 2; break;                        
            case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget: size = 1; break;
            case OperandType.ShortInlineI: size = 1; break;
            case OperandType.ShortInlineR: size = 4; break;                        
            case OperandType.ShortInlineVar: size = 1; break;
            default:                        
                    throw new Exception("Unknown operand type.");                        
        }
        size += opcode.Size;

        int token = 0;
        if (str == "call" || str == "callvirt")
        {
            //если это вызов метода, найдем токен
            token = (((msil[n + 1] | (msil[n + 2] << 8)) |
                (msil[n + 3] << 0x10)) | (msil[n + 4] << 0x18));

            //надем метод в текущем модуле по токену
            var method = module.ResolveMethod(token);
            if(!methods.Contains(method))methods.Add(method);
        }

        n += size; //пропускаем нужное число байтов
    }

    return methods;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
public static int F(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

public static void Test()
{
    int x = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int y = 0;
    Func<int,int> lambda = (x) => F(x) > F(y) ? F(y) : F(x / 2);

    var methods = GetCalledMethods(lambda.Method);
    sb.AppendLine("Lambda calls:");
    foreach (var x in methods) sb.AppendFormat("- {0}.{1}()\r\n", x.DeclaringType.ToString(), x.Name);
    sb.AppendLine();

    methods = GetCalledMethods(this.GetType().GetMethod("Test"));            
    sb.AppendLine("Test method calls:");
    foreach (var x in methods) sb.AppendFormat("- {0}.{1}()\r\n", x.DeclaringType.ToString(), x.Name);

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Должно вывести что-то такое:

> Lambda calls:
>   - WindowsFormsTest.Form1.F()
>
> Test method calls:
>   - System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
>   - System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Id()
>   - System.Int32.ToString()
>   - System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()

Что касается изменения кода методов во время выполнения, это значительно сложнее, но тоже возможно. См. например здесь: [.NET CLR Injection: Modify IL Code during Run-time](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time)