# Как можно запретить добавлять в проект вызовы некоторых методов?

Tags: c#

Есть какие-либо приёмы запрещающие добавлять в код проекта, вызовы определенных методов? Кроме организационных, конечно.
В частности, хочу убрать возможность использовать все перегрузки `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()` не содержащие параметр `IWin32Window owner`:

```
Show(String)
Show(String, String)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions, Boolean)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions, String)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions, String, HelpNavigator)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions, String, HelpNavigator, Object)
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton, MessageBoxOptions, String, String)
```

Comment: нет............

Comment: @Grundy в этом мире можно все, главное - найти подход)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, без вспомогательных инструментов нельзя ;-)

Comment: @Grundy, безусловно, но разве стоит себя ограничивать в них?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Здесь упоминалось решение с Roslyn API, его тоже несложно сделать.

Для начала, создадим анализатор, как показано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756891/10105). Мы не можем придумать разумный code fix, поэтому у нас будет лишь анализ и подсвечивание красной волнистой линией.

Код нашего анализатора такой:

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace OverloadAnalyzer
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class OverloadAnalyzerAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public const string DiagnosticId = "OverloadAnalyzer";

        private static readonly string Title = "MessageBox.Show only with owner";
        private static readonly string MessageFormat = "Use overload with owner";
        private static readonly string Description =
            "You must always specify an owner for MessageBox.Show";
        private const string Category = "Framework usage";

        // соберём описание нашего правила
        private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category,
            DiagnosticSeverity.Error, // укажен, что это ошибка, а не предупреждение
            isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

        // список диагностик, которые мы выдаём
        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics =>
            ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

        // при инициализации подпишемся на анализ всех команд вызова функции
        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol,
                                             SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
        }

        // сам анализатор
        private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            // получаем синтаксический узел, приводим его к типу «вызов функции»
            var invocationNode = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

            // мелкая эвристика для ускорения: если среди имён в выражении нет Show,
            // дальнейший дорогой семантический анализ не имеет смысла
            if (!invocationNode.DescendantNodes()
                               .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
                               .Any(n => n.Identifier.ValueText == "Show"))
                return;

            // получаем символ у семантической модели
            var symInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationNode);
            var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)symInfo.Symbol;
            // если его нет (например, у нас некомпилирующийся код), отваливаем
            if (methodSymbol == null)
                return;

            // проверяем, что это действительно вызов MessageBox.Show
            if (methodSymbol.ContainingAssembly.Name != "System.Windows.Forms")
                return;
            if (methodSymbol.ContainingType.ToDisplayString() !=
                    "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox")
                return;

            // если в списке параметров есть параметр с типом IWin32Window, всё хорошо
            if (methodSymbol.Parameters.Any(p => p.Type.Name == "IWin32Window"))
                return;

            // иначе говорим юзеру «атата!»
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationNode.GetLocation());
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}
```

Получаем вот такое поведение:

[image: а я Roslyn ещё больше ку!]

Если вы хотите ещё и проверять код во время построения (а то вдруг программист отключит анализатор или не использует Visual Studio?), вам нужно будет написать ещё и анализатор командной строки, аналогично тому, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810044/10105), и запускать его при построении на build-сервере (или в post-build step).

У меня получился вот такой анализатор командной строки:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace CommandLineOverloadAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: CommandLineOverloadAnalyzer.exe SolutionPath" +
                              " MSBuildPath [\"batch\"]");
            Console.WriteLine("if batch specified, no extra output is done");
            Console.WriteLine("if no batch specified, MSBuildPath may be omitted" +
                              " and will be asked for if needed");
        }

        static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            if ((args.Length < 1 || args.Length > 3) ||
                (args.Length == 3 && args[2] != "batch"))
            {
                Usage();
                return 1;
            }
            var solutionPath = args[0];
            var msBuildPath = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : null;
            bool batchMode = args.Length == 3;

            // найдём версию MSBuild
            var visualStudioInstances =
                MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray();
            var instance =
                // указан путь, выбираем его
                (msBuildPath != null) ? visualStudioInstances.SingleOrDefault(
                                                   i => i.MSBuildPath == msBuildPath) :
                // только одна студия, выбираем её
                visualStudioInstances.Length == 1 ? visualStudioInstances[0] :
                // в пакетном режиме? падаем
                batchMode ? null :
                // спрашиваем у юзера
                SelectVisualStudioInstance(visualStudioInstances);
            if (instance == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot determine MSBuild path");
                return 1;
            }

            void Out(string s)
            {
                if (!batchMode)
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Out($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

            // Экземпляр MSBuildLocator должен быть зарегистрирован
            // перед MSBuildWorkspace.Create(), иначе MEF-композиция не сработает
            MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);

            bool hadProblems = false;
            using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
            {
                // Напечатаем сообщение при приходе WorkspaceFailed, чтобы
                // помочь с диагностикой проблем загрузки проектов
                workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (o, e) => Out(e.Diagnostic.Message);

                Out($"Loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

                // печатаем прогресс при интерактивной загрузке
                var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath,
                    batchMode ? null : new ConsoleProgressReporter());
                Out($"Finished loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

                foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
                {
                    Out($"Processing project {project.Name}");
                    var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

                    // для каждого файла в проекте отдельное синтаксическое дерево
                    foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
                    {
                        var root = await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync();
                        // создаём семантический анализатор
                        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
                        // получаем все типы переменных
                        foreach (var invocationNode in root.DescendantNodes()
                                             .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>())
                        {
                            if (!invocationNode.DescendantNodes()
                                               .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
                                               .Any(n => n.Identifier.ValueText == "Show"))
                                continue;

                            var symInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(invocationNode);
                            var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)symInfo.Symbol;
                            if (methodSymbol == null)
                                continue;
                            if (methodSymbol.ContainingAssembly.Name !=
                                    "System.Windows.Forms")
                                continue;
                            if (methodSymbol.ContainingType.ToDisplayString() !=
                                    "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox")
                                continue;

                            if (methodSymbol.Parameters.Any(p => p.Type.Name ==
                                    "IWin32Window"))
                                continue;

                            var location = invocationNode.GetLocation().GetLineSpan();
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                $"MessageBox.Show usage is wrong, location = {location}");
                            hadProblems = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return hadProblems ? 1 : 0;
        }

        private static VisualStudioInstance SelectVisualStudioInstance(
            VisualStudioInstance[] visualStudioInstances)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiple installs of MSBuild detected, please select one:");
            for (int i = 0; i < visualStudioInstances.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Instance {i + 1}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    Name: {visualStudioInstances[i].Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    Version: {visualStudioInstances[i].Version}");
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"    MSBuild Path: {visualStudioInstances[i].MSBuildPath}");
            }

            while (true)
            {
                var userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(userResponse, out int instanceNumber) &&
                    instanceNumber > 0 &&
                    instanceNumber <= visualStudioInstances.Length)
                {
                    return visualStudioInstances[instanceNumber - 1];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted, try again.");
            }
        }

        private class ConsoleProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress>
        {
            public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress)
            {
                var projectDisplay = Path.GetFileName(loadProgress.FilePath);
                if (loadProgress.TargetFramework != null)
                {
                    projectDisplay += $" ({loadProgress.TargetFramework})";
                }

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{loadProgress.Operation,-15}" +
                    $" {loadProgress.ElapsedTime,-15:m\\:ss\\.fffffff}" +
                    $" {projectDisplay}");
            }
        }

        private class SilentProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress>
        {
            public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress) { }
        }
    }
}
```

В Post-Build step укажите просто

```
"<путь к анализатору>\CommandLineOverloadAnalyzer.exe" "$(SolutionPath)" "$(MSBuildBinPath)" batch
```

У меня при пробном пробеге вывело:

> MessageBox.Show usage is wrong, location = <полный путь>\RoslynTest\SampleApp\Program.cs: (13,12)-(13,46)

Comment: А значение параметров можно проверять? типа если пришел `null` - то ошибка

Comment: @Grundy: Можно, но зачем? Злонамеренный программист найдёт возможность передать `null`, присвоив его через вспомогательную переменную или через метод наподобие `T CreateNull<T>() { if (new Random().Next(1) != -1) return null; else return CreateNull<T>(); }`

Comment: кстати, а разве `new Random().Next(1) == -1` хоть когда-то будет `true`?

Comment: @Grundy: Никогда. Это для того, чтобы было сложно понять при помощи анализатора, что метод всегда возвращает `null`

Comment: А на сколько вообще можно определить значение переданное? Например если просто `var a = null; func(a)` - будет ясно, что передан `null`?

Comment: _Никогда._ - тогда метод будет падать с переполнением а не null возврашать :)

Comment: @Grundy: flow analysis может показать, если значение вычисляется локально и не зависит от библиотечных функций, по идее.

Comment: @Grundy: Угу. Исправил код.

Comment: @Grundy: Вот пример с flow analysis: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: Крууууутоооо!!!

Answer (score 7):

Стандартно нет. А вот например в решарпере есть [External Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) которые позволят добавить атрибуты, например [Obsolete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), к стороннему коду.

Comment: ну это по большей части тоже "организационная" мера, т.к. необходимо что-бы все использовали решарпер. Он же не является обязательным инструментом для написания кода, может я в Vim-е пишу или еще в какой экзотике. Но информация сама по себе интересна, спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

Можно написать свою программу для этих целей, воспользовавшись [существующими наработками по парсингу MSIL-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866161/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Напишем вот такую программу, принимающую на вход путь к сборке, и возвращающую код 0, если она не содержит вызовов запрещенных методов, или код 1 при их наличии (код неэффективный по производительности, воспринимайте только как пример):

```
//Утилита для проверки сборки на наличие вызовов запрещенных методов
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace AssValidator
{
    class Program
    {

        public static OpCode FindOpCode(short val)
        {
            OpCode ret = OpCodes.Nop;
            FieldInfo[] mas = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
                if (mas[i].FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
                {
                    OpCode opcode = (OpCode)mas[i].GetValue(null);
                    if (opcode.Value == val)
                    {
                        ret = opcode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        //получает список методов, вызываемых указанным методом
        public static List<MethodBase> GetCalledMethods(MethodBase mi)
        {
            MethodBody mb = null;

            //получаем тело метода
            try
            {
                mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().ToString() + " " + ex.Message);                
            }
            if (mb == null) return new List<MethodBase>();

            //получаем IL-код
            var msil = mb.GetILAsByteArray();

            //получаем модуль, в котором расположен метод
            var module = mi.Module;

            List<MethodBase> methods = new List<MethodBase>();

            short op;
            int n = 0;

            //парсим IL-код...
            while (true)
            {
                if (n >= msil.Length) break;

                //получаем код операции
                if (msil[n] == 0xfe)
                    op = (short)(msil[n + 1] | 0xfe00);
                else
                    op = (short)(msil[n]);

                //найдем имя операции
                OpCode opcode = FindOpCode(op);
                string str = opcode.Name;
                int size = 0;

                //найдем размер операции
                switch (opcode.OperandType)
                {
                    case OperandType.InlineBrTarget: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineField: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineMethod: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineSig: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineTok: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineType: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineI: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineI8: size = 8; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineNone: size = 0; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineR: size = 8; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineString: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineSwitch: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.InlineVar: size = 2; break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget: size = 1; break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineI: size = 1; break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineR: size = 4; break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineVar: size = 1; break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unknown operand type.");
                }
                size += opcode.Size;

                int token = 0;
                if (str == "call" || str == "callvirt")
                {
                    //если это вызов метода, найдем токен
                    token = (((msil[n + 1] | (msil[n + 2] << 8)) |
                        (msil[n + 3] << 0x10)) | (msil[n + 4] << 0x18));

                    //найдем метод в модуле по токену
                    try
                    {
                        var method = module.ResolveMethod(token);
                        if (!methods.Contains(method)) methods.Add(method);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                n += size; //пропускаем нужное число байтов
            }

            return methods;
        }

        //получает список методов, вызываемых всеми классами в указанной сборке
        public static List<MethodBase> GetCalledMethods(Assembly ass)
        {
            List<MethodBase> methods = new List<MethodBase>();
            var types = ass.GetTypes();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var t in types)
            {                
                //поиск по методам...
                var mlist = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
                foreach (var m in mlist)
                {
                    var arr = GetCalledMethods(m);
                    foreach (var x in arr)
                    {
                        if (!methods.Contains(x)) methods.Add(x);
                    }
                }

                //поиск по конструкторам...
                var clist = t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
                foreach (var m in clist)
                {
                    var arr = GetCalledMethods(m);
                    foreach (var x in arr)
                    {
                        if (!methods.Contains(x)) methods.Add(x);
                    }
                }


            }
            return methods;
        }

        //проверяет указанную сборку на наличие вызовов запрещенных методов
        static bool ValidateAssembly(string path)
        {            

            Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(path); //загружаем сборку

            var methods = GetCalledMethods(ass); //получаем все вызываемые методы

            foreach (var x in methods)
            {
                var pars = x.GetParameters();

                //вызов метода System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string) запрещен
                if (x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox"
                    && x.Name == "Show"
                    && pars.Length == 1
                    && pars[0].ParameterType.Name == "String"
                    )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Method call not allowed: MessageBox.Show(String)");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true; //не найдено запрещенных методов
        }

        //AssValidator - точка входа
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: too few arguments!");                
                Environment.Exit(0xff);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Validating "+args[0]+" ...");

            try
            {
                bool res = ValidateAssembly(args[0]);
                if (!res) { Console.WriteLine("Assembly is invalid"); Environment.Exit(1); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Assembly is valid"); Environment.Exit(0); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validation error!");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(0xff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Соберем ее (желательно в режиме Release, так как процесс довольно тяжелый), и разместим полученный файл так, что путь к нему будет, допустим, `D:\Distr\AssValidator\AssValidator.exe`.

В свойствах проекта, на вкладке "События построения", зададим событие после построения:

```
"D:\Distr\AssValidator\AssValidator.exe" $(TargetPath)
```

Теперь, при попытке собрать проект с запрещенным методом получим ошибку построения

```
error MSB3073: выход из команды ""D:\Distr\AssValidator\AssValidator.exe" d:\...\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" с кодом 1.
```

Выглядит это как-то так:

[image: VS screeshots]

Протестировано для .NET 4.5 / VS 2012.

Недостатки способа:

- В ходе проверки сборки может быть выполнен код из нее (например, статические конструкторы). В том числе, этот код может упасть с исключением и нарушить все.
- Чтобы работало для не-*AnyCPU* проектов, понадобится две версии проверяющей программы (32-битная и 64-битная)
- Хотя при непрохождении проверки построение завершается с ошибкой, сам скомпилированный файл сборки остается. Опять же, можно создать BAT-файл, удаляющий сборку при неудачном результате проверки.

Comment: Хм, интересно. А что-то подобное с использованием Roslyn API и анализом исходного кода, а не скомпилированной сборки можно сделать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Думаю да, реализация поиска методов в коде у нас уже есть (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810832/Как-получить-список-всех-вызываемых-методов-в-коде-c-roslyn), а прикрутить ее к студии по аналогии можно через "Событие перед построением".

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Добавил решение на Roslyn.

Comment: @VladD, круто, спасибо!