# Создание dll с Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Пробую создать dll библиотеку c Roslyn. Добавил все библиотеки с NuGet для работы с Roslyn. Но корректно работать она не хочет. Может кто-то имел дело с такой же проблемой, подскажите. 
При OpenSolutionAsync(path), не видит проектов.

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
IEnumerable<Project> projects = solution.Projects;
```

Заметил такую вещь.
Поле выполнения

```
Solution solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
```

workspace.Diagnostics присутствует такое сообщение. " Инициализатор типа "Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileMatcher выдал исключение".
[image: Ошибка при открытие solution]

Comment: на картинке непонятно что проверяется и показывается

Comment: @Grundy , указал детальнее.

Comment: а по указанному пути точно есть solution?

Comment: @Grundy, да, вот если создаю проект "Extensibility => Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool" и делаю тоже самое, все нормально и все работает. Но хочу сделать dll, и не работает. Может вы имели дело в создании dll с Roslyn ?

Comment: Попробуйте как во втором примере [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876456/10105).

Comment: @VladD, мне нужно создать именно библиотеку (.dll), после чего подключить к другому проекту и использовать. У меня как-бы в моей dll будет не большой анализатор. Может я не так что-то делаю, вы не имели дела с созданием dll с Roslyn ?)

Comment: @Kisa777: А вы пробовали второй вариант? Есть подозрение, что в вашем коде нет `MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance`.