# Как ограничить использование атрибута другим атрибутом?

Tags: c#, рефлексия, атрибуты

Имеется пользовательский атрибут `ForEnum` нацеленный на использование с перечислением. Ещё один пользовательский атрибут `ForProp` нацелен на использование со свойствами и полями. Каким образом указать, что атрибут `ForProp` можно использовать только если перечисление декорировано атрибутом `ForEnum`?

```
[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Enum, 
    AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ForEnumAttribute : Attribute { }

[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, 
    AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ForPropAttribute : Attribute { }

[ForEnum]
public enum AnyEnum {
    [ForProp]
    Unknown = 0,
    [ForProp]
    One = 1,
    [ForProp]
    Two = 2
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите? Чтобы вам как-то ругалось при компиляции или исключение в рантайме подойдет?

Comment: @АндрейNOP чтоб ругалось при компиляции.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно запретить добавлять в проект вызовы некоторых методов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875165/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ищу способ без использования статических анализаторов, т.к. на мой взгляд это как из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Бросайте исключение в рантайме. Другого способа я не знаю (но это не значит, что его нет)